# Kubuntu LiveUSB kernel panic on boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel, kubuntu

I am attempting to install Kubuntu 18.04.1 on my AMD Ryzen 5 based computer, however I get a kernel panic when booting from the USB disk.

The computer's specs:
Ryzen 5 - 2600
ASRock B450m Pro4
16GB DDR4-2133
AMD RX-470.

I have observed multiple Kernel panics:
corrupted stack end detected inside scheduler
Fatal exception in interrupt

As well as hangs on the splash screen (the text "Kubuntu" still "breaths")

Answer (score 1):

Could be a kernel issue. I personally couldn't install an OS with kernel below 4.17 on my Ryzen 2500U.

- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cant-get-the-live-cd-to-boot-on-ryzen-5-2400g/41009
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/8v9eeb/state_of_ryzen_3_2200g_and_linux/

Comment: So from what it sounds like, I need to install the 18.10 version for now and wait for the next LTS release?

Comment: I unfortunately am not sure what kernel the 18.10 install has.